# How to know the server performance is good by using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Is there any benchmark to know the server performance. And which listener is more useful for find the server performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check server performance by different factors like..

- Response Time
- Concurrency
- Throughput

Response time, throughput etc requirements could vary from application to application. It really depends on application, business nature. These are normally derived by business analysts/clients.

Listeners just present you the info in different ways and all of them are important in their own way. I mostly use aggregate graph listener and loadosophia listener (plugin) to get reports. There are many other listeners available in Jmeter-Plugins and all of them are good in their own way.

For more details check:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing
http://www.testerlogic.com/performance-testing-types-concepts-issues/